# Apply a set of functions to multiple data frames, considering a specific sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Consider this data:

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), V2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), V3 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), V4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), V5 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), V6 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0), V7 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), V8 = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), V9 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -46L))
```

I would like to apply the following functions for all possible pairs in `df`.

Applying to the pair `V1` and `V2`:

```
df$V1V2 <- (df$V1 * df$V2) + (1 - df$V1) * (1 - df$V2)
sum <- (sum(df$V1V2)/46)
df$VD <- (df$V1/sd(df$V1))
df$VI <- (df$V2/sd(df$V2))
est <- lm(df$VD ~ df$VI)
summary(est)
ndf <- data.frame(NA)
ndf$V1V2 <- summary(est)[["coefficients"]][, "Pr(>|t|)"][2]
```

Applying to the pair `V1` and `V3`:

```
df$V1V3 <- (df$V1 * df$V3) + (1 - df$V1) * (1 - df$V3)
sum <- (sum(df$V1V3)/46)
df$VD <- (df$V1/sd(df$V1))
df$VI <- (df$V3/sd(df$V3))
est <- lm(df$VD ~ df$VI)
summary(est)
ndf$V1V3 <- summary(est)[["coefficients"]][, "Pr(>|t|)"][2]
```

I could apply this to all other pairs of `V1` (i.e. `V3`, `V4`, `V5`, `V6`, `V7`, `V8`, and `V9`). Nonetheless, I am sure this is not the best approach.

**UPDATE**

This is how far I got:

```
dfV1 <- df[, c("V1", "V2", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V4", "V1", "V5", "V1", "V6", "V1", "V7", "V1", "V8", "V1", "V9")]
colnames(dfV1) <- c("V1", "V2", "V1", "V3", "V1", "V4", "V1", "V5", "V1", "V6", "V1", "V7", "V1", "V8", "V1", "V9")

sep <- lapply(seq(1, ncol(dfV1), by=2), function(i) 
  dfV1[i: pmin((i+1), ncol(dfV1))])

V1V2 <- sep[[1]]
V1V3 <- sep[[2]]
V1V4 <- sep[[3]]
V1V5 <- sep[[4]]
V1V6 <- sep[[5]]
V1V7 <- sep[[6]]
V1V8 <- sep[[7]]
V1V9 <- sep[[8]]

list_V1 <- tibble::lst(V1V2, V1V3, V1V4, V1V5, V1V6, V1V7, V1V8, V1V9)

library(dplyr)
my_func <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>%
    mutate(First = (x[,1] * x[,2] + (1 - x[,1] * (1 - x[,2]))),
           VD = x[,1] / sd(x[,1]),
           VI = x[,2] / sd(x[,2]))
}

res <- lapply(list_V1, my_func)
list2env(res, .GlobalEnv)

df.IC.V1 <- cbind.data.frame(V1V2$First, V1V3$First, V1V4$First, V1V5$First, V1V6$First, V1V7$First, V1V8$First, V1V9$First)
IC.all.V1 <- data.frame(colSums(df.IC.V1)/46)
```

I do not know how to apply this part to the list `dfV1`:

```
est <- lm(df$VD ~ df$VI)
summary(est)
ndf$V1V3 <- summary(est)[["coefficients"]][, "Pr(>|t|)"][2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid wide data and keep data long or [tidy](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html) which helps in virtually every aspect of data science: aggregation, modeling, and plotting. Therefore, consider `reshape` (or tidy semantics of `pivot_longer`) to reformat data to long and with a generalized method, call `by` to run your model by each of the 9 different variables.

Finally, you may want to separate out results of this process in a new data frame to avoid repetition of values in original due to different lengths and especially since your model outputs two rows for intercept and variable with multiple columns.

```
long_df <- reshape(df, idvar="V1", varying=names(df)[-1], 
                   times=names(df)[-1],
                   v.names="value", timevar="variable", 
                   new.row.names=1:1E4, direction="long")

pairwise_model <- function(sub) {
   sub$vpair <- (sub$V1 * sub$value) + (1 - sub$value) * (1 - sub$value)
   sum_v <- (sum(sub$vpair)/46)
   sub$VD <- (sub$V1/sd(sub$V1))
   sub$VI <- (sub$value/sd(sub$value))
   est <- lm(VD ~ VI, data=sub)
   print(summary(est))

   ndf <- data.frame(variable = sub$variable[[1]],
                     summary(est)[["coefficients"]])
   return(ndf)
}

df_list <- by(long_df, long_df$variable, pairwise_model)

results_df <- do.call(rbind, df_list) 

results_df
#                variable    Estimate Std..Error    t.value     Pr...t..
# V2.(Intercept)       V2  0.70897157  0.1697361  4.1769050 1.376794e-04
# V2.VI                V2  0.20546559  0.1475392  1.3926169 1.707334e-01
# V3.(Intercept)       V3  0.00000000  0.4324256  0.0000000 1.000000e+00
# V3.VI                V3  0.29294628  0.1441419  2.0323471 4.818178e-02
# V4.(Intercept)       V4  0.59719677  0.1461565  4.0860091 1.829775e-04
# V4.VI                V4  0.47663445  0.1325296  3.5964390 8.118808e-04
# V5.(Intercept)       V5  0.77259722  0.1604268  4.8158874 1.766754e-05
# V5.VI                V5  0.13627939  0.1493492  0.9124883 3.664845e-01
# V6.(Intercept)       V6  0.68720490  0.1557572  4.4120255 6.533736e-05
# V6.VI                V6  0.31399751  0.1431310  2.1937768 3.357833e-02
# V7.(Intercept)       V7  0.57392936  0.1516681  3.7841150 4.627413e-04
# V7.VI                V7  0.46128020  0.1337587  3.4486009 1.253140e-03
# V8.(Intercept)       V8  0.90047538  0.1869717  4.8161045 1.765498e-05
# V8.VI                V8 -0.09345783  0.1500959 -0.6226544 5.367256e-01
# V9.(Intercept)       V9  0.60871296  0.1645124  3.7001029 5.960399e-04
# V9.VI                V9  0.35598290  0.1408800  2.5268512 1.517916e-02
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/RXPT59287)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It's perfect. Also thanks for your hints, I'll keep it in mind.